# populating sqlalchemy table with csv file having foreign key saves null to database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, flask-sqlalchemy

Am trying to populate my table using csv with foreignkey constraints. the problem is it saves all as none in the database. After reading the csv file, i change the list to a dictionary (song_params). I dont no where i could have got it wrong beacuse all seems to be the way i wanted it to work

```
header = ['artist', 'album', 'genre', 'song', 'price', 'download_link', 'duration']
            for row in csv_file:

                song_params = dict(zip(header, row))
                song_values = {}
                dbsession = DBSession()

                for key, value in song_params.iteritems():



                    if key == 'artist':
                        martist = dbsession.query(Artist).filter_by(artist = value).first()
                        song_values['artist'] = martist

                    else:
                        song_values[key] = value


                    if key == 'album':
                        malbum =dbsession.query(Album).filter_by(album_name = value).first()
                        song_values['album'] = malbum
                    else:
                        song_values[key] = value

                    if key == 'genre':
                        mgenre = dbsession.query(Genre).filter_by(genre = value).first()
                        song_values['genre'] = mgenre
                    else:
                        song_values[key] = value


                song = Song(song_values)          
                dbsession.add(song)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Song(**song_values)` - unpack dict to an argument list.

Comment: Song(**song_values) pops AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'